# XML Validation: Error Parsing Attribute Name

Tags: javascript, xml-validation

I've got an XML validation problem. This bit:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
oxm_ad = {"website":"cca9e4b4-7ed2-848z-ffea-067efabc891a",
"size":"468x60",
"floor":"0.01",
"beacon":"<div id='beacon_017a6c9ega' style='position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; visibility: hidden;'><img src='http://www.website.com/openx/www/delivery/lg.php?bannerid=1&amp;campaignid=1&amp;zoneid=4&amp;loc=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%2fproject-debug%2fproject.html&amp;cb=014a7c8eda&amp;bannerid=-1' width='0' height='0' alt='' style='width: 0px; height: 0px;' </img></div>",
"fallback":"<a href='http://www.website.com/openx/www/delivery/ck.php?oaparams=2__bannerid=1__zoneid=4__cb=014a7c8eda__oadest=http%3a%2f%2fwww.website.com' target='_blank'><img src='http://www.website.com/openx/www/delivery/ai.php?filename=mybanner.png&amp;contenttype=png' width='468' height='60' alt='' title='' border='0' /></a><div id='beacon_014a7c8eda' style='position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; visibility: hidden;'><img src='http://www.website.com/openx/www/delivery/lg.php?bannerid=1&amp;campaignid=1&amp;zoneid=4&amp;loc=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%2fproject-debug%2fproject.html&amp;cb=014a7c8eda' width='0' height='0' alt='' style='width: 0px; height: 0px;' </img></div>"};
</script>
```

results in:

> This page contains the following
>   errors: error on line 5 at column 246:
>   error parsing attribute name

I'm not sure what my error is. Any suggestions on how to correct this problem?

Thank you!

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the end `>` on both of your `<img>` tags. I.e. it should be:

```
<img src='... height: 0px;'> </img>
```

Instead of what you currently have:

```
<img src='... height: 0px;' </img>
```

The next line has the same error. See if that fixes the problem?

Comment: Thank you, eldarerathis!! The missing </img> tags solved the problem. 

All the best,

Answer (score 0):

`<img>` tag now has no paired `</img>` end tag instead use `<img src="...." />`